# Issues with my Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains list of semesters.On pressing any of the semester a new activity will be created and prompts user to enter marks in each subject of semester to calculate percentage.I have two options:

1)To create a new activity for every semester when pressed which is tedious

2)To create  a single activity but to change text views according to button
 press.

I chose the second one.But unfortunately I chose `ListView` to change the `TextView`.[This is how my activity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaGqJ.png)

But I am facing  problems.

1)When I enter marks in a row.The same marks are repeated in bottom row.For example when I enter Marks in M1 the same is getting repeated in EnglishLab.
I expect the problem is with `ListView`

This is the XML which my `adapter` for `ListView` inflates in `getView` method

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:text="subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"

    android:textColor="@color/black"


    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     />
<EditText
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:id="@+id/ScanText"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
    android:inputType="number"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code for `getView` method.Here the `adapter` is implemented as an inner class to `MarksEntering` activity(which contains listview layout)

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sidebyside, parent, false);

                Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Congratulations!Your % is"+ percentage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });



            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ScanText);
            editText.setCursorVisible(true);
            textView.setText(str[position]);


            return convertView;

        }
```

The XML file in which my `ListView` resides is:

```
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>




<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"



    android:id="@+id/submitbutton"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the submit button is below list view.So to calculate the percentage I need to get an instance of `EditText`(In order to get the marks entered in EditText).But I am not able to get it. When  I am using `LayoutInflater` I am not getting `ViewGroup` for layout in which `EditText` is present.So is there anyway so that I can overcome these two problems(getting `ViewGroup`and overcoming the repitition of marks).Or do I have to use other `View` instead of `ListView`

Comment: why you  have two ? `convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sidebyside, parent, false);` and 
               `View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.marksentering, parent, false);`

Comment: sorry for that it was mistake while copying and pasting the code..however I have deleted it now.